# Check when image view is touched

Tags: android, collision-detection, detect

I am trying to create a game in which the user will press down their finger and hold it there. As there finger is pressed down, little, "asteroids" will be falling down that the user must dodge. I am trying to find a way to switch the boolean `start` to false when an asteroid passes under the users finger. There are 16 asteroids all coming down at different speeds.

```
   this.ob1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
    @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view == findViewById(R.id.obstacle1)) {     
                     start = false;
        }
        }
    });
```

I have tried this code, but to no prevail. Any help would be greatly appretiated.

Comment: Could you distill the code dump to the _relevant_ part, which contains what you've tried to do to solve the problem?

Comment: @uri I have tried and failed by using a touch listener, but I ended up deleting it

Comment: Ask yourself whether all the code you added to the question really helps us understand your problem - and delete all that is unnecessary.

Comment: @UriAgassi I fixed it, if you'd like to look at it.

Comment: Much better! Well done